# Wool batting window quilt?

Tags: insulation, windows, energy-efficiency, materials, winter

Would it make sense to use wool batting like [this](https://www.etsy.com/listing/474550961/100-pure-new-wool-batting-by-the-yard?gpla=1&gao=1&) as a window quilt? Why or why not? What factors would affect its suitability?

For context, I propose using this on the inside of one of those [shrink film kits](https://www.frostking.com/products/window-kits/indoor-shrink-window-kits) in the US midwest.

Comment: Nothing about it being flame-retardant so it might help to burn your house down if it got ignited by something.

Comment: Aha, good point. That would keep me warm but have other side effects....

Comment: Wool insulation is available that meets the fire regs (in the country where I bought and used it). There is also wood insulation, again meets fire regs and I used a 30cm thickness of that on my build to really get a low heating requirement.

Comment: I argue that this is not a duplicate. It is asking about a different material than the fiberglass question. Some evidence for the value of this question is that it precipitated the above fire safety conversation. The mere fact that my question has the same objective as the linked question does not make it the same question.